# Getting error while setup drools 6 with spring 4-The method processData(LicenseCredential) is undefined for the type Rule_Renewal_alert_for_60]

Tags: spring, java-8, drools, kie

I am new to Drools. I setup a new project with spring-4.1 and drool-6.1.0.Final. But when I try to run project I get the following errors

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'autoalert-ksession-stateless': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'autoalert-kbase' while setting bean property 'kBase'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'autoalert-kbase': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while creating KieBase[Message [id=1, level=ERROR, path=drools/rules/Rule.drl, line=27, column=0
text=[ function processDataprocessData (line:27): learnerCsvFileWriter cannot be resolved
]], Message [id=2, level=ERROR, path=drools/rules/Rule.drl, line=33, column=0
  text=Rule Compilation error The import defaultpkg.ProcessData cannot be resolved
The method processData(LicenseCredential) is undefined for the type Rule_Renewal_alert_for_60_days2039807096], Message [id=3, level=ERROR, path=drools/rules/Rule.drl, line=-1, column=0
text=Error importing : 'defaultpkg.ProcessData.processData']]
```

Here are my spring and drools configuration files

drools-context.xml

```
<kie:kmodule id="autoalert-module">
    <kie:kbase name="autoalert-kbase" packages="drools.rules">
        <kie:ksession name="autoalert-ksession-stateless" type="stateless"  />
    </kie:kbase>
</kie:kmodule>

<bean id="kiePostProcessor" class="org.kie.spring.KModuleBeanFactoryPostProcessor"/>
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<context:annotation-config />              
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:autoalert.properties" ignore-unresolvable="true" /> 

<import resource="classpath:database/datasource-tx.xml" />
<import resource="classpath:drools/drools-context.xml" />

<bean id="csvFileWriter" class="com.softech.vu360.autoalert.CsvFileWriter" />

<bean id="businessRuleProcessor" class="com.softech.vu360.autoalert.rule.BusinessRuleProcessor">
    <property name="statelessKieSession" ref="autoalert-ksession-stateless" />
    <property name="csvFileWriter" ref="csvFileWriter" />
</bean>
```

Here is my rule file.

```
import com.softech.vu360.autoalert.util.Utility;
import static com.softech.vu360.autoalert.util.Utility.getCurrentDate;
import static com.softech.vu360.autoalert.util.Utility.getDate;
import static com.softech.vu360.autoalert.util.Utility.getMonthNameFromInt;
import com.softech.vu360.autoalert.model.LicenseCredential;
import com.softech.vu360.autoalert.model.Learner;
import com.softech.vu360.autoalert.CsvFileWriter;
import com.softech.vu360.autoalert.mail.EmailRegistrationService;
import java.util.Date;

global com.softech.vu360.autoalert.CsvFileWriter learnerCsvFileWriter;

function void processData(LicenseCredential licenseCredential){

    Learner learner = new Learner();
    learner.setLearnerName(licenseCredential.getLearnerName());  
    learner.setLearnerEmailAddress(licenseCredential.getLearnerEmailAddress());
    learner.setUserGUID(licenseCredential.getUserGUID());
    ...
    learnerCsvFileWriter.add(learner);

}

rule "Renewal alert for 60 days"
    when
        licenseCredential : LicenseCredential()
        (
            eval(licenseCredential.getRenewalDeadlineDay() == "0" && licenseCredential.getRenewalDeadlineMonth() == "0") && 
            eval(getCurrentDate().after(getDate(2, licenseCredential.getCourseCompletionDate().getDate(), licenseCredential.getCourseCompletionDate().getMonth()+1))) && 
            eval(getCurrentDate().before(getDate(1, licenseCredential.getCourseCompletionDate().getDate(), licenseCredential.getCourseCompletionDate().getMonth()+1))) 
         ) ||
        (
            eval(getCurrentDate().after(getDate(2, Integer.valueOf(licenseCredential.getRenewalDeadlineDay()), Integer.valueOf(licenseCredential.getRenewalDeadlineMonth()) ))) &&
            eval(getCurrentDate().before(getDate(1, Integer.valueOf(licenseCredential.getRenewalDeadlineDay()), Integer.valueOf(licenseCredential.getRenewalDeadlineMonth() )))) 
        )
    then
        System.out.println("Rule For 60 Days Called");      
        processData(licenseCredential);
end
```

Here is my POM file:

```
<properties>
    <java-version>1.8</java-version>
    <junit.version>4.12</junit.version> 

    <!-- Spring -->
    <org.springframework.version>4.1.4.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>

    <!-- Drools -->
    <drools.version>6.1.0.Final</drools.version>
    <drools-maven-plugin.version>6.0.0.CR5</drools-maven-plugin.version>

    <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.2</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
   ...

    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

</properties>

<dependencies>

    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    ....
    <!-- Drools -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
        <artifactId>kie-api</artifactId>
        <version>${drools.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
        <artifactId>kie-ci</artifactId>
        <version>${drools.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
        <artifactId>kie-spring</artifactId>
        <version>${drools.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jbpm</groupId>
        <artifactId>jbpm-bpmn2</artifactId>
        <version>${drools.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <plugins>

        <!-- Maven compiler plugin -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java-version}</source>
                <target>${java-version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        ....
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${drools-maven-plugin.version}</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Here is my main file

```
public static void main(String[] args){ 

    final ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:spring/applicationContext.xml");

    LicenseCredentialDAO dao = (LicenseCredentialDAOImpl)context.getBean("licenseCredentialDAO");
    List<LicenseCredential> objectList = dao.select();

    BusinessRuleProcessor ruleProcessor = (BusinessRuleProcessor)context.getBean("businessRuleProcessor");
    ruleProcessor.configureAndApplyRulesOnObject(objectList);

    CsvFileWriter learnerCsvFileWriter = context.getBean("csvFileWriter", CsvFileWriter.class);
    learnerCsvFileWriter.writeCsvFile("abc.csv");

}
```

Here is my BusinessRuleProcessor class

```
public class BusinessRuleProcessor {
    private StatelessKieSession statelessKieSession;
    private CsvFileWriter csvFileWriter;

    // getters and setters

    public void configureAndApplyRulesOnObject(List<LicenseCredential> objectList){

        statelessKieSession.setGlobal("learnerCsvFileWriter", csvFileWriter);
        statelessKieSession.execute(objectList);

    }
}
```

Why I am getting error that

```
function processDataprocessData (line:27): learnerCsvFileWriter cannot be resolved

Rule Compilation error The import defaultpkg.ProcessData cannot be resolved

The method processData(LicenseCredential) is undefined for the type Rule_Renewal_alert_for_60_days2039807096]
```

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: I have a feeling that it may relate to the issues you have with package definitions. It looks like you didn't bother setting a package name for your rule (hence `defaultpkg`), but you put it in package; `drools/rules/`.

Comment: you mean to say I need to define package declaration in my rules file. Like `package drools.rules;` in my drl file ?

Comment: It's a starting point. Drools looks for rules defined in packages under `src/main/resources`, following Java style package structures. Just like a Java class, if a rule is in the `drools/rules` directory, then it should declare its package as `drools.rules`.

Comment: I defined the package in my `Rule.drl` file like `package drools.rules;`, But now error message just change to `Rule Compilation error The import drools.rules.ProcessData cannot be resolved`

Comment: So your rules file is now: `src/main/resources/drools/rules/ProcessData.drl`?

Comment: I'm also a bit concerned that your pom.xml is importing 2 different versions of the Drools libraries. It's also setting a property for a third, but that doesn't seem to be used.

Comment: No my rule file is `src/main/resources/drools/rules/Rule.drl` and on the top of file I declared import like `package drools.rules;` . Do I need to change my file name from `Rule` to `ProcessData` ?

Comment: btw - Did the rule compile and activate before you added the function?

Comment: No it gives me error when I try to initializa spring context i.e. on the very first line in my main() function. At line `final ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:spring/applicationContext.xml");` . When this line execute then I get the errors.

Comment: I meant - did you create a version of the rule which worked without any calls to globals, etc, before you added that? If you develop the application in smaller increments, it's easier to see which change introduced the bug. But try @laune's change first. There's a chance that it's the only thing you need to fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's strange that an error is indicated in a function processDataprocessData, which isn't in the DRL you have posted, but there is another error saying that there is no function processData, which appears in the DRL. Did you falsify the code?

But the problem is simply that you cannot reference a global within a function. To use the global, pass it as a parameter.

```
function void processData(LicenseCredential licenseCredential,
                          CsvFileWriter learnerCsvFileWriter ){
    ....
}

rule ...
then
    System.out.println("Rule For 60 Days Called");      
    processData(licenseCredential, learnerCsvFileWriter);
end
```

All complaints to the Drools team, please!

Comment: Ah ... Thanks man. This is working. Many thanks to you.  I thought by defining global variable you can use it anywhere without passing it to functions. Anyways thanks again. But I didn't do anything. I don't know why it is showing `processDataprocessData,` in the logs. As I said I am drools newbie. But all the errors are gone and now it is working perfectly. Thanks to you and Steve ;) :)